# Why all are indexes in my list of lists 0?

Tags: python, list, indexing

I want a flashcard software with decks and cards. I created a general list all_decks. I created a class for the decks:

```
 class deck(list): 
    def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name
    def open_deck(self):
            print "This is your deck %s: " %(self.name)
            print "This deck has %s cards." %(len(self)) 
            return self
```

The deck is then created with user input for the name and appended to all_decks. This is the function to print them:

```
def print_decks():                                                      
    print "You have %s decks: " %(len(all_decks))
    for x in all_decks:
            print all_decks.index(x), x.name
```

This does print a list of all the decks, but all indexes appear to be 0. Why? Also I thought I would use indexes for the "open deck" and "delete deck" functions but it's not working.

Comment: You never showed where you create `all_decks`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misunderstood what `index()` does. It returns the index of the first element in the list that matches your target. But you never defined a way of comparing decks.

You don't really want to use index here. Instead, keep count with `enumerate`:

```
for i, x in enumerate(all_decks):
        print i, x.name
```